# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o703.load. : Failed to find data source: com.crealytics.spark.excel in azure synapse

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have a problem with reading  the excel using pyspark, I have installed the jar in the azure synapse workspace
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.11/0.13.7

but still I got the issue, please help me how can I fix this.
here is my code :

```
df=spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(xlContestSourcePath)
```

here is my error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o725.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.package$.Seq()Lscala/collection/immutable/Seq$;
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$.<clinit>(WorkbookReader.scala:32)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:22)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:13)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:8)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:315)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:241)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Seems the library is not loaded properly. Please check this-https://dustinvannoy.com/2022/01/05/synapse-spark-add-jars/.If it still does not work. Please create a ticket with Support

Comment: Hi Subash, I am not able to access the dustinvannoy.com/2022/01/05/synapse-spark-add-jars/.If , I got 403 Forbidden error

Comment: My bad the link is  https://dustinvannoy.com/2022/01/05/synapse-spark-add-jars/